# Jaspersoft iReport Can we do subtotals in a list component?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I just wish to know if it is possible to do subtotals in a list component? If so, is it like using a variable and putting the reset type as 'Group' and putting the expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many limitations of List component (calculations, return values, headers and footers, ...).
See section "13.1.3 List Component Issues" in ireport-ultimate-guide.

Try to use subreport instead list. It is more suited for computation on a subset of data

Comment: Thank you so much sanBez.. yea i read that section but i just wanted to make sure... :)

Comment: Lists are under-powered for subtotals (as sanBez writes) but... subreports might be over-powered for your problem (they'll certainly work, but they add complexity). The table component might be just right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

1. First you create a variable in the dataset then open variable properties, set calculation sum
   Set variable expression which field you want to sum from list component (like `$F{paidAmount}`) and save
2. Create a variable in the main report 
   Open report XML source then go at position  in list component and  assign value from dataset to main variable like this way

   ```
   <returnValue fromVariable="sumOfPayment"toVariable="mainSumOfPayment"/>
   ```

Example :

```
<datasetRun subDataset="CreditorList" uuid="6aebc237-1aa2-47db-9435-8b133cef2b31">
 <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{invoices}]]></dataSourceExpression>
 <returnValue fromVariable="sumOfPayment" toVariable="mainSumOfPayment"/>               
</datasetRun>
```

3. then drag the mail variable to the possible you what to show sum that list component field out side of list .and open the variable properties panel and must set Evaluation Time -Report